how to get the EC2 instances which are connected to FSx using boto 3?
i'm trying to get the ec2 instances which are using a FSx as their storage source.i'm using boto3 module for this . how to get the ec2 instances?
i tried describe_instances() method from boto3. idea was to get the pass the fsx id first. then get the storage details using describe_instances().

I wonder if it is even possible? FSx volumes are mounted within the operating system, so AWS probably doesn't know which instances are using which volumes.
